# Timing Measurements of Linux kernel routine

Tags: c, linux, performance, linux-kernel

I added some additional code to the Linux kernel (the scheduler)
and now I would like to know what is the impact of this modification.

For user processes I always used:

```
clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, ...);
```

Now I am wondering if there is a kernel-equivalent routine that I could
use to do something similar.

Many thanks for your assistance,
Martin

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at ftrace. Latencytop is based on that. There are good articles at lwn ([here](http://lwn.net/Articles/365835/), [here](http://lwn.net/Articles/366796/), and [here](http://lwn.net/Articles/370423/))

Measuring scheduler performance is notoriously hard, so good luck :)

Comment: THanks for that I will have a look at it. However, is there also something similar as the clock_gettime in Linux?

Comment: There is, but you don't want to try doing it that way in the kernel.  ftrace is the right thing, it does all the hard parts for you.

Answer (score 2):

`unsigned long long native_sched_clock(void);` from `asm/timer.h` for x86

`unsigned long long sched_clock(void);` from `linux/sched.h` for any arch

They are wrappers around `rdtsc` - tick counter reader.

upd.

there is also `linux/clocksource.h`

```
timecounter_init - initialize a time counter
timecounter_read - return nanoseconds elapsed since timecounter_init()
```